# How to get every combination of multiple arrays in python in memory efficient way?

Tags: python, list, memory, combinations, python-itertools

I want to get all the combination of 3 arrays in python(python 3.6).
I've searched similar question and got answer that use itertool.product.
I tried it but it doesn't work(maybe because of memory).

My code:

```
from itertools import product

a = [i for i in range(500)]
b = [j for j in range(5000)]
c = [k for k in range(10000)]
result = list(product(a,b,c))
```

When I run this in jupyter notebook, kernel dies. And during running, my mac's memory is full.
How can I solve this problem in memory efficient way?

Comment: len(result) is 2.5*10E10, too big, if you need work with all the combinations, consider divide and conquer

Comment: You are creating a large list, right?  What size do you expect?  What do you hope to do with this list once you create it?

Comment: @gamesun dive and conquer? OK. Actually I don't get how to use divide and conquer in getting combination(I'm very newbie)..but I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: @hpaulj my example's size is what I expect in size.
In more detail, I have list of seller ids, item ids, buyer ids. And I want to know all the combination of those. And you that combination list as test data of machine learning model. I can aggregation existing log by three ids, but then I only get observed combination. I want to know all the combination.

Comment: That's 25 billion combinations!!!